# Irrelevant warning while running git command from bash

Tags: git, git-bash

When I execute a git command (e.g. `git push origin master`) from bash I see some warning coming as -

`git: 'credential---help' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

More details from log:

```
$ git push origin xxx --force
git: 'credential---help' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
Enumerating objects: 71, done.
Counting objects: 100% (71/71), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (37/37), done.
Writing objects: 100% (44/44), 22.86 KiB | 668.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 44 (delta 26), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote:
...
```

And then the command executes successfully.

I am not able to understand why I am getting this error and how to get rid of it.

Comment: Perhaps that is part of the output that is being fed from server? Because that doesn't look like anything I've ever seen coming out of a git push.

Comment: It looks like something to do with Git's support for credentials storage.  Do you see anything in the output of `git config --list | grep credential`?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials You should have a look here.

Comment: @larsks the output looks like `credential.helper=manager 
credential.helper=wincred
credential.helper=--help`. I need to update the config it seems :) Pls add as an answer, will accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may have a bad credentials helper configuration on your local machine.  Take a look at the output of `git config --list | grep credential` to find the relevant configuration options.

You can find documentation on Git's credentials support [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage).

Comment: Got rid of by running this command `git config --unset credential.helper`